# OrderBy clause is breaking my OData Service implemented using Apache Olingo

Tags: java, odata, olingo

I have developed a OData service using Apache Olingo.When I query with URL containing 'OrderBy',it is throwing error whereas query without OrderBy is running fine.
Successful URL-http://localhost:8081/PeopleFinderService/peoplefinderservice.svc/EqxIntranetPeopleFinders?$select=EmpId&$inlinecount=allpages&$top=26
Failure URL-http://localhost:8081/PeopleFinderService/peoplefinderservice.svc/EqxIntranetPeopleFinders?$orderby=EmpId&$select=EmpId&$inlinecount=allpages&$top=26

```
    HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: org/apache/commons/codec/DecoderException

type Exception report

message org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: org/apache/commons/codec/DecoderException

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: org/apache/commons/codec/DecoderException
    org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)
    org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:331)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:223)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:203)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:137)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:243)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:168)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:219)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: Please advise how to fix the above error

Answer (score 0):

At first,there was a corrupted JAR in my lib and replacing it with correct JAR  got me above error which says missing class/JAR.I downloaded missing JAR from http://apache.arvixe.com//commons/codec/binaries/ and it fixed my issue